# Login to iOS application using fingerprint when one device is shared by multiple users

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, fingerprint, touch-id

We have a requirement where we need to login in to our application using fingerprints. We do understand that apple touch id can be used for authentication purpose and only returns success or failure in the response.

However, in our case one iPhone device will be shared by 5 to 8 users and we need to map an unique userId with each saved fingerprint to identify the user.

Is there any way to map a userid with the saved fingerprint (any unique number returned from an api like Fingerprint1, Fingerprint2 will do)?

Or Is there any alternative solution to login to our iOS application using biometric data?

We dont't want to add an extra fingerprint scanner device.

Comment: `any unique number returned from an api like Fingerprint1, Fingerprint2 will do )` --> **NO**,it returns only success or failure,

Comment: alternate way you need to store custom data in keychain once you get success

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Can I save data corresponding to a fingerprint? We can't share the login credentials among multiple users.

Comment: Can I save data corresponding to a fingerprint - no is not possible, share the login credentials among multiple users - dont share but you can store in keychain with encryprted format with help of username/email (its the prrimary Object), I did like this my current app.

Comment: once your authentication success you to retrieve based on the current primary key and call your API or UI updation based on your need

Comment: But with this we'll not be able to identify which user has logged in. All will be using the same account. Right?

Comment: yes - but if biometrics authentication user risk and security only, at present apple has did like this

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative approach for login (other that having a external fingerprint scanner) where user does not need to enter any kind of pin/password.

Answer (score 2):

No, You can't achieve this in iOS. According to Apple about biometric

> Touch ID doesn't store any images of your fingerprint. It stores only
>   a mathematical representation of your fingerprint. It isn't possible
>   for someone to reverse engineer your actual fingerprint image from
>   this mathematical representation. The chip in your device also
>   includes an advanced security architecture called the Secure Enclave
>   which was developed to protect passcode and fingerprint data.
>   Fingerprint data is encrypted and protected with a key available only
>   to the Secure Enclave. Fingerprint data is used only by the Secure
>   Enclave to verify that your fingerprint matches the enrolled
>   fingerprint data. The Secure Enclave is walled off from the rest of
>   the chip and the rest of iOS. Therefore, iOS and other apps never
>   access your fingerprint data, it's never stored on Apple servers, and
>   it's never backed up to iCloud or anywhere else. Only Touch ID uses
>   it, and it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.

Now come to main point.

Now days iPhone X series is more popular than other, and they don't support Touch ID, also you can store only one Face ID per device. not like the Touch ID (with multiple finger).

Or after certain wrong try of finger print the device will locked and you have provided Passcode, This is also one per device.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way for you to know how many and which finger was used for biometrics, the secure enclave only lets you know if the biometric check has passed or not.